# Using TLS 1.2 from java 6

Tags: ssl, java, tomcat

We have a legacy web application that runs in a tomcat under java 6, upgrading to 7 or 8 is infeasible as the application needs significant work to allow this and the fixes required are too large to implement in a legacy application. We now have a requirement to connect outbound (i.e. as a client) over TLS 1.2 however java 6 only supports 1.0. We use Apache as our web-server and OpenSSL for incoming connections and this happily supports TLS 1.2 etc.

Has anyone had to address a similar issue, or can you comment on the following potential work arounds:

- Loopback to localhost (or otherwise redirect) and use OpenSSL to create a TLS 1.2 connection,

  - effectively an internal proxy
  - can openssl be a client?
  - do we need s_client?
- Use our current the firewall to upgrade the connection

  - this would need to be selective
  - Obviously implementing this will depend on the firewall
- Use “Bouncy Castle” (https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Comment: It is unlikely an application running under Java 6 won't run with JRE 7. Have you tried? Bouncy Castle can be a good option as it can transparently replace the security provider from the JRE, but you have to do a lot of testing to ensure compatibility.

Comment: We tried java 7 and it broke. Regression testing is largely automated so that will be less of an issue.

Comment: AFAIK, JDK 6 doesn't receive security updates anymore, so using it is not a good idea. Even of it does get updates, due to the many issues with Java's TLS implementation, I would not use Java for a TLS server. Put nginx as a reverse proxy / TLS terminator in front of the Tomcat, let nginx handle the TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use openssl's s_client for this - it's slow, and intended more for debugging/testing.

Try using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html). It's designed for use cases like yours, and you can find plenty of example configs to get you started. You'd want to make sure to include the `sslVersion = TLSv1.2` directive in your configuration to force use of TLS 1.2.